# How to add onto end of value in nested list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

EDITED:  I didn't realize you all want valid code.. I was just using examples, but here you go:

I have a complex problem that I can't seem to find searching stackoverflow.  Using Python3.6

I have a "list of dictionaries", with example entries such as this.  All keys/values are str.

```
mylist = [ {'0.0.0.0': { 'name': 'server1', 'port': '80', 'description': 'http' },
           {'1.1.1.1': { 'name': 'server2', 'port': '2341', 'description': 'foobar' }
         ]
```

I've already found code to search to see if the dictionary contains a dictionary key "ipaddr" given a specific value.

What I want to do is this.

setting variable info = "morestuff"

Search and change the 1.1.1.1 dictionary entry to look like

{ '1.1.1.1': { 'name': 'server2', 'port': '2341', 'description': 'foobar morestuff' }

effectively "appending" the "info" str variable onto the end of the 'description' value.

Comment: `dict['1.1.1.1']['description'] += ' ' + newinfo`?

Comment: Are your keys and terminal values strings?

Comment: Why is `dict` a list?

Comment: @huck_cussler Not only that, but it's a bad variable name simply because of shadowing `dict`.

Comment: @erip And it's invalid syntax.

Comment: It's missing closing curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

First, your dic is a list instead of dictionary. (BTW, your code is invalid)

For example, we have the following code.

```
dic = [{'0.0.0.0': {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First'}},{'1.1.1.1': {'Name': 'Aa', 'Age': 9, 'Class': 'Second'}}]
```

From what I understand, you want to update the info by appending or adding a new string. Since it is a list, you should call index first

```
dic[0]['0.0.0.0']['Class'] += 'what'
```

Output

```
'Firstwhat'
```

---

You have to change your dictionary structure as the following:

```
dic={'0.0.0.0': {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First'}, '1.1.1.1': {'Name': 'Aa', 'Age': 9, 'Class': 'Second'}}
```

input

```
dic['1.1.1.1']['Class'] += 'thinking'
```

output of dic

```
{'0.0.0.0': {'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First', 'Name': 'Zara'},
 '1.1.1.1': {'Age': 9, 'Class': 'Secondthinking', 'Name': 'Aa'}}
```

Comment: This doesn't work though if you change your indicator to 1.1.1.1

dic = [{'0.0.0.0': {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First'}},{'1.1.1.1': {'Name': 'Aa', 'Age': 9, 'Class': 'Second'}}]

dic[0]['1.1.1.1']['Class'] += 'what'

KeyError: '1.1.1.1'

Comment: Hi Galt, as what I said. It is a list. To call 1.1.1.1. You have to do this dic[1]['1.1.1.1']['Class'] += 'what'

Comment: Ugh.. ok what I'm trying to do is search this dictionary, matching on 1.1.1.1, and if found, append that info.  So I won't know what position the dictionary is located.